# CodeIgniter sess_destroy does not delete user_data session?

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating test case for my CodeIgniter app. However I just found something that I thought should not be happen :

in login.php controller  :

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('/');
}
```

So I just created a test to just make sure that session is really destroyed :

```
public function test_logout()
{
     $this->CI = set_controller('login');
    // make sure that all session is destroyed
    $this->CI->session->set_userdata('test_session', 'some_value');
    $this->CI->logout();
    // userdata 'test_session' should be removed!
    $this->assertTrue(($this->CI->session->userdata('test_session')==null || $this->CI->session->userdata('test_session')==''));

}
```

However I find that upon running the test case, my test case fails! Upon debug on the last line of test case, I found that the userdata is still exist with value = 'some_value'. I thought that sess_destroy should also delete all the set user data, as per what they described in their [website documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html):

> This function should be the last one called, and even flash variables will no longer be available. If you only want some items destroyed and not all, use unset_userdata().

I am using Kenji's CIUnit for unit testing.
Is this the correct behaviour or is there something that I missed?

Comment: you can use 'unset_userdata()' function as well!

Comment: yeah, but if the developer keep adding new session name, it will be a lot to call, or have to call all_userdata() or something.

Comment: it's hard for me to understand your workflow, how are you testing it... after calling "logout", you should be redirected. Remember, session in cookies are session in the database could exist at different times.

Comment: it should not be possible to call the assertTrue line once you have redirected from the logout function

Comment: in CIUnit Test Case you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that CIUnit routes the Session to CIU_Session instead of original CodeIgniter's CI_Session. It miss a line that CI_Session does :

```
$this->userdata = array();
```

So turns out this is CIUnit's issue instead of CodeIgniter's. Create [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit/issue/24/sess_destroy-does-not-delete-user_data) in their bitbucket page.